# Xamarin Forms Command always null in custom control

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, icommand

I try to create a usercontrol. The user control will be a Button to show loader.

I try to pass a binded command from my page to my control

My XAML PAge is:

```
                <sharedviews:ButtonLoader TextLabel="{extensions:Translate Save}"   BackgroundColorButton="{StaticResource RedColor}" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Center" Animation="Cupertino" TextColorIndicator="White" 
                                          TextColorLabel="White"  VerticalOptions="End" Command="{Binding ValidateMandatoryCommand}" TextWaiting="{extensions:Translate Saving...}" />

                <Button HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="150" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="0,10,0,0"  HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Style="{StaticResource ValidButtonStyle}" FontSize="15" Padding="5"
                    Text="{extensions:Translate Next}"
                            Command="{Binding ValidateMandatoryCommand}" />
```

WHen I use the command ValidateMandatoryCommand in the standard button it works well. When I use it in my custom button (sharedviews:ButtonLoader) it's always null. This confirms that my command ValidateMandatoryCommand works well.

My XAML of my custom button looks like:

```
 <ContentView.Content>
    <Grid>
        <buttons:SfButton x:Name="btn" Clicked="btn_Clicked" CornerRadius="30" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <buttons:SfButton.Content>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                    <busyindicator:SfBusyIndicator IsVisible="False" x:Name="busyIndicator" AnimationType="Cupertino" IsBusy="True" TextColor="White" WidthRequest="40" ViewBoxWidth="40"/>
                    <Label x:Name="labelLoader" Text="Loading..." FontSize="15" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White" />
                </StackLayout>
            </buttons:SfButton.Content>
        </buttons:SfButton>
    </Grid>
</ContentView.Content>
```

My C# code of button loader for my command is

```c#
     public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(ButtonLoader), default(ICommand), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);
        public ICommand Command
        {
            get
            {
                return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
            }
        }

     private async void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelLoader.Text = TextWaiting;
            busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
            busyIndicator.IsVisible = true;

            //if (Command != null) <= //**Always NULL**
            //{
                await Task.Run(() => {
                    Command.Execute(null);
                });

            //}


            busyIndicator.IsVisible = false;
            busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
            labelLoader.Text = TextLabel;
        }
```

> EDIT based on the comments

My ValidateMandatoryCommand is defined as:

```
public ICommand ValidateMandatoryCommand => AsyncCommand.Create(ValidateMandatory);

    private async Task ValidateMandatory()
      {}
```

And the AsyncCommand

```
   public class AsyncCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private readonly ICommand _command;

    protected AsyncCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        _command = command;
        command.CanExecuteChanged += (sender, args) => CanExecuteChanged.InvokeSafely(sender, args);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _command.CanExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _command.Execute(parameter);
    }

    public static AsyncCommand Create(Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> func)
    {
        return new AsyncCommand(new Command(async () => await func()));
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm LGTM. Can you show us your viewmodel (your BindingContext / the class that contains `ValidateMandatoryCommand` respectively) and how you set it?

Comment: Really can't reproduce it. Can you also show the full source of you custom view?

Comment: I see you are using BindingMode.TwoWay which in some cases may result in overwriting the ViewModel's command so maybe check that too in your button's codebehind and your page's viewmodel. Also I would recommend using this implementation of async command in order to avoid any silent exceptions with yours. https://github.com/brminnick/AsyncAwaitBestPractices/blob/master/Src/AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM/AsyncCommand.cs

Comment: What @xerx said. Plus: I wouldn't recommend using `ValidateMandatoryCommand => AsyncCommand.Create(ValidateMandatory);` This will create a new command for each time `ValidateMandatoryCommand` is accessed. `ValidateMandatoryCommand { get; private set; }` and initialize it in your constructor

Comment: ok thanks. I will fix this. But how do you explain that my command works with the button and it's null with my custom button?

Comment: as I said. I can't really reproduce it :< Else I would have given a proper answer.

Comment: @dalton5 Hi , have you solved this ? If so , remember to share the solution in answer when you have time :-) .

Answer (score 0):

If you inherit your View from Button, then you need to change the name of your BindableProperty. The Button class already has a property with the same name.